# Where can I find a concise comparison of Java (swing, JWS) versus HTML/JS for RIA

Tags: java, html

Looking to implement a RIA (rich internet application) either as a java (JWS) application or HTML/CSS/JS. I have been looking for resources that show a clear pro's con's on the subject, but haven't been able to find a nice comparison. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: JWS is a way of launching desktop applications in a new window from a web page. If you're writing an application that should live inside the browser, JavaFX is the more appropriate technology to consider. But I'm not aware of a resource that compares JavaFX to HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: I guess my question is a little confusing. I guess what I am asking is a comparison of a GUI developed with Swing (deployed as JWS) or HTML/JS. Something that lays out the pros and cons of both, limitations, etc.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a comparison of exactly these two technologies because they're used to build entirely different kinds of applications. Are you looking for a comparison of desktop vs. web applications?

Comment: We currently have a distributed application and are having numerous issues with the technology originally used to build the GUI components and are looking to overhaul it. Apart of the discussion was whether we should build the GUI portion as a swing application and use java RMI to communicate with the backend or go with another HTML/CSS/JS approach. Was just looking for compelling arguments for both sides so we can weigh the decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a short argument, here are the key differences :

- A web applciation will reside in the browser, intermix a bunch of maybe integrable technologies (html, javascript, css, server-side applciation programming, ...) while a Swing java web startable application will require on client side only a small XML knowledge (even automatable using maven jnlp depoloyment packaging).
- On the connection point of view, a browser application will require you to use only HTTP communication protocol, while a Swing web started application will allow you to use any kind of protocol you want, provided a Java implementation exists, obviously.
- On the deployment side, it's quite identical : you deploy your application server-side, and a mechanism allows user to get it on its machine. However, using JNLP, you can allow user to have a start menu item for your application, making next launches faster than by requiring him to navigate to your site.

In fact, i think it's only a question of desired user experience. If you want your users to consider your application as a shared "site", the web application is the development model of choice.

However, if you want your users to consider your application as a work application, then Swing+JWS is the solution of choice. It integrates in many OSes, deploys over http (and hence can enter deep in enterprises networks without having to worry about firewalls more than a web site) and will allow you to provide far more integrationf eatures (drag'n'drop to OS, respect to native look'n'feel or to your company look'n'feel, and so on).